# symfony2 generating obj from form type

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I've written a little symfony2 application which allows you to ask a question, every question has at least one task and is asked by an user.

but currently I've the following Error

"Neither the property "question" nor one of the methods "getQuestion()", "isQuestion()", "hasQuestion()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "NAMESPACE(Question)".:"

And I really dont know why there is this error, it would be verry helpfull if anyone could explain what this error causes.
And why symfony thinks that the Question Entity should have one of those methods.

Here are the classes:

The Question Class (entity),

```
class Question extends Post
{
/*
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $id;
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PLACEHOLDER")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="You should select at least one tag.")
 */
protected $tags;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="You have to input a heading.")
 */
protected $heading;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="You have to enter a question text.")
 */
protected $text;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
protected $date;

/**
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PLACEHOLDER")
 */
protected $user;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->tags = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
// GETTERS / SETTERS .... 
}
```

The Question Type Class (form),

```
class QuestionType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('tags', 'entity', array( 'class'=>'fully qualified class name(tag)',
                                        'property'=>'name'))
        ->add('heading', 'text')
        ->add('question', 'textarea')
        ->add('submit', 'submit')
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'fully qualified class names (Question Entity)'
    ));
}


/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'PLACEHOLDER';
}
}
```

and the Question Controller action :

```
public function askQuestionAction(Request $request)
{

    $form = $this->createForm(new QuestionType, new Question);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // persist
    }

    return array('form' => $form->createView());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to bind the form to a `Question` entity with

```
$form = $this->createForm(new QuestionType, new Question);
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

You have a `question` on the form which `handleRequest` will try and bind to the `Question` entity.

Looking at your code, shouldn't `->add('question', 'textarea')` actually be `->add('text', 'textarea')`?

Answer (score 0):

This `PLACEHOLDER(Namespace to Question Entity)` and this `PLACEHOLDER(Namespace to Tag class)`. Those should be **fully qualified class names**.

Eg. `MyVendor\MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity`

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake while writing the question, I meant full qualified class names.
In the application it are already full qualified class names